# python pandas consolidate rows with same values in a sequence and reorder (drop duplicates in a sequence)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Lets say i have following table:

```
ID    FRUIT    ORDER
01    apple    1
01    apple    2
01    peach    3
01    apple    4
02    melon    1
02    apple    2
02    apple    3
02    apple    4
```

Now i want to consolidate rows within same ID when the values are equal in a iterative manner (drop duplicates if they are in a sequence) and redefine the order number, e.g.

```
ID    FRUIT    ORDER
01    apple    1
01    peach    2
01    apple    3
02    melon    1
02    apple    2
```

**EDIT: I forgot to reorder. Like above: the order should be re-arranged in an iterative manner**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter only first consecutive values with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for new ordering:

```
a = df['ID'] + df['FRUIT']
#if necessary
#a = df['ID'].astype(str) + df['FRUIT']
df = df[a.ne(a.shift())]
df['ORDER'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
   ID  FRUIT ORDER
0  01  apple     1
2  01  peach     2
3  01  apple     3
4  02  melon     1
5  02  apple     2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will be easy one to go :

```
>>> df
   ID  FRUIT  ORDER
0  01  apple      1
1  01  apple      2
2  01  peach      3
3  01  apple      4
4  02  melon      1
5  02  apple      2
6  02  apple      3
7  02  apple      4

>>> df[df['FRUIT'] != df['FRUIT'].shift(1)]
   ID  FRUIT  ORDER
0  01  apple      1
2  01  peach      3
3  01  apple      4
4  02  melon      1
5  02  apple      2
```